# Why does matching group exist but does not really match?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Why the next code does not match the word **SELECT**?

```
import re

re_q = r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.*\d*\+\d{2}\s|\s(SELECT).*'

raw_q = "2014-01-23 15:28:32.993995+04 | SELECT query_start, query from pg_stat_activity WHERE state='active'"

m = re.match( re_q, raw_q )

for i in range( 1, 8 ):
    print "Group <{0}>: {1}".format( i, m.group( i ) )
```

Output:

```
Group <1>: 2014
Group <2>: 01
Group <3>: 23
Group <4>: 15
Group <5>: 28
Group <6>: 32
Group <7>: None
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) since it matches in [the second round](http://regex101.com/r/bN9fH1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax),

> '|'
>
> A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular
>   expression that will match either A or B. An arbitrary number of REs
>   can be separated by the '|' in this way. This can be used inside
>   groups (see below) as well. As the target string is scanned, REs
>   separated by '|' are tried from left to right. When one pattern
>   completely matches, that branch is accepted. This means that once A
>   matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a
>   longer overall match. In other words, the '|' operator is never
>   greedy. **To match a literal '|', use \|, or enclose it inside a**
>    **character class, as in [|].**

`|` means `OR` in Regular expression language. You have to escape that also, with `\`. So, `\s|\s` should have been `\s\|\s`. After fixing that, I get

```
Group <1>: 2014
Group <2>: 01
Group <3>: 23
Group <4>: 15
Group <5>: 28
Group <6>: 32
Group <7>: SELECT
```